# What is the best open-source email solution package

Tags: email, postfix

I need to set up a mail server on an Ubuntu Linux box. Instead of starting from scratch I'm looking for an all in one package, like a bundle that offers a complete but minimal and light weight solution.

I'd like this bundle to have at least the following characteristics; based around Postfix, some form of spam handling and a web interface the manage accounts etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Complete but minimal and light weight solution".  Uhm...

Just build it yourself.  It'll be a lot more flexible, and you'll have a better chance of fixing it when it breaks.  The components I'd use are:

- Postfix
- bogofilter (spam filtering)
- Postfixadmin (for the web interface)
- Dovecot (IMAP/POP access)

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck with [Zimbra](http://www.zimbra.com/) at a previous company. The web interface is nice and all the components are self-contained, and the support forums are wonderful. It is basically all the popular open source mail tools bundled together with a slick interface.

However, these days I would (and do) outsource my mail handling to Google Apps for my domain.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget about Exim.  Its a pretty straight forward, clearly documented (make that excellent documentation) and well supported by it's community.  I have used Qmail, Postfix, and Exim.  Exim without a doubt has served me best.

Of course the whole thing is subjective and any of the mentioned applications would work just as good as any other.

Answer (score 1):

Second the recommendation to outsource.  Yes, you *could* set up and run a mailserver yourself, but that means you're the one getting the page at oh-dark-thirty when something breaks.  I like Fastmail, but there are plenty of other companies out there (e.g. Google).

If you need to run this system in-house for some reason, Zimbra meets your requirements and my employer's instance (supported by a 24-hour NOC) works fairly well.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to do some setup of several components, that's the linux way - take a MTA, a spam tool, a web server etc etc.

However, your request is one that many people already want, so the steps to put them all together are well documented.

Try [this one](http://www.howtoforge.com/groupware-server-with-group-office-postfix-dovecot-spamassassin-on-debian-lenny) for example (plenty of other good setups in that site too)

For a web interface to practically everything, make sure you look at [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/). It is the essential admin tool I use, next to ssh!

there are a few that have a lot of features all-in-one, but I think you'll still need to set up the MTA separately. For example, there's [Horde](http://www.horde.org/) or [Zimba](http://www.zimbra.com/) which appear to be good groupware servers.